# Hosting ASP.NET on Raspberry Pi 3B+ for local network

Tags: asp.net, .net, raspberry-pi

I am trying to host an API (ASP.NET) on my Raspberri Pi 3B +. I would like to access this API swagger page from my laptop/phone/pc etc.

What I've tried until now:
Installed, compiled, built and ran the web application with dotnet on my RPi.

running `dotnet --info`  on the RPi provides us the following information:

```
.NET SDK (reflecting any global.json):
 Version:   5.0.405
 Commit:    63325e1c7d

Runtime Environment:
 OS Name:     raspbian
 OS Version:  11
 OS Platform: Linux
 RID:         linux-arm
 Base Path:   /usr/share/dotnet/sdk/5.0.405/

Host (useful for support):
  Version: 5.0.14
  Commit:  d5b56c6327

.NET SDKs installed:
  5.0.405 [/usr/share/dotnet/sdk]

.NET runtimes installed:
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 5.0.14 [/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 5.0.14 [/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]
```

When I run the program (filepath `~/first-rpi-api/bin/Release/net5.0/publish/first-rpi-api`)

I get the following:

```cs
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Now listening on: http://localhost:5000
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Now listening on: https://localhost:5001
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Hosting environment: Production
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Content root path: /home/pi/first-rpi-api/bin/Release/net5.0/publish
```

The default URL for the swagger UI would be : `https://localhost:44335/swagger/index.html`
However when I try to access the API from my PC on URL : `https://RPi_IP:5000/swagger/index.html`

I get `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`

How do I fix this ? Have I missed something and how would I approach this problem ?

Comment: Obvious question: do you need to open that port on the firewall?

Comment: `Now listening on: http://localhost:5000` does it work over HTTP instead of HTTPS? i.e. `http://RPi_IP:5000/swagger/index.html`

Comment: I don't want to access it from external network, just locally from other devices on my network. And @phuzi no, changing from https to http doesn't work.

Comment: Putting swagger aside for the moment, can you access the API over the network?

Comment: No, the url for that would be ```http://RPi_IP:5001/WeatherForecast ``` however this also results in ```ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED```

Comment: Hmm, 5001 appears to be HTTPS and HTTP appears to be 5000. Could you try HTTP on port 5000?

Comment: Already tried both, and they don't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the previous answer (refering to omajid's answer) provides us only a temporary solution.

Whenever you reboot the Raspberry Pi you would need to execute the command

```cs
export ASPNETCORE_URLS="http://*:5000;https://*:5001"
```

again and again.

To prevent this, I suggest using the `IHostBuilder.UseUrls("URLS")` method.

In your case you would need to edit your `Program.cs` and add the following line in the CreateHostBuilder method.

```cs
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
                {
                    webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();

                    //THIS LINE
                    webBuilder.UseUrls("http://*:5000;https://*:5001"); 
                });
```

This will automatically ensures that you can access the API from whichever device you'd like.

You can read more about this in this [article](https://andrewlock.net/5-ways-to-set-the-urls-for-an-aspnetcore-app/) :

Comment: This solved my issue, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

```
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Now listening on: http://localhost:5000
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Now listening on: https://localhost:5001
```

Listening on `localhost` means that it's only listening to network connections from the same machine (which is the Raspberry Pi, in your case). If you want it to listen to network connections from outside the machine, you need to listen to `0.0.0.0`.

Without seeing your code that sets up network conncetions, it's hard to be sure what a fix that would integrate well would look like but try doing this before running your program:

```
export ASPNETCORE_URLS="http://*:5000;https://*:5001"
```

That will make your application allow connections from anywhere.

Comment: Where do i need to put this ```export ASPNETCORE_URLS="http://*:5000;https://*:5001"``` ? Also the code can found if you create a new ASP.NET Core Web API project in Visual Studio

Comment: After changing the launchSettings.json > ```"applicationUrl": "https://+:5001;http://+:5000"``` and retrying, I still get the same error ```ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED```

Comment: You need to run it in the terminal before you run `~/first-rpi-api/bin/Release/net5.0/publish/first-rpi-api`. As for launchSettings.json, is it even used? Do you see an updated `Now listening on ...` message?

Comment: No, changing the applicationUrl did not change the ```Now listening on ...```. I did try the export command and now I got the response. Thank you!